# WPF: Call property changed callback after all properties are set

Tags: wpf

I have a custom control where I have two dependency properties defined  `ItemSourceProperty` and `ItemTemplateProperty` (this is just an example).

When the control is created, I'd like to handle the initial set of the properties together:

`<MyControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}" />`

This is order to avoid creating the view for every item twice. When the control is created, let's suppose `PropertyChangedCallback` of the `ItemSourceProperty` is called first. At this time the `ItemTemplate` will be null. If I create views at this point, the views will not have the template. When `PropertyChangedCallback` is called for `ItemTemplate`, I have to recreate views, this time using the template.

How can I implement it in a way such my initialization is called after the framework sets the initial values of `ItemSourceProperty` and `ItemTemplateProperty`?

It will still need to work in the case when user sets only one of the properties

`<MyControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`

Comment: Attach a Loaded event handler and check if any of the properties have other values than their default values.

Comment: @Clemens but the `PropertyChangedCallback` will still be called for every property.

Comment: Sure, and they have to be called in order to react on property value changes. However, your question is about "*the initial values*".

Comment: I mentioned it needs needs to work with property changed callback

Comment: What makes you think it won't work with PropertyChangedCallback? A Loaded event handler could easily set a flag that indicates whether some kind of initial value check was already performed.

Comment: @JamesL: Check whether the other property has been initialized in the PropertyChangedCallback? If it hasn't you could simply return and do nothing.

Comment: What I mean is, even with Loaded event, `PropertyChangedCallback` are still called. I could maybe have a flag like `_isLoading` which I could check inside the property changed callbacks and return if it's `true`. On Loaded I could set the flag to false. But I need to be sure Loaded does not come first or in between the property changed callbacks

Comment: I was wondering if there isn't an easier way...

Answer (score 0):

The properties are set one after another wich means that your callbacks will be invoked one after another. What you could do is to check whether the other property has been initialized in the `PropertyChangedCallback` of the first one and vice versa. If it hasn't you could simply return and do nothing.

Or you could handle the `Loaded` event of your control and check the state of both properties in the event handler.

But there is no way you can prevent a `PropertyChangedCallback` for a property A to get invoked before another property B has been set. You don't know when and even if this property will ever be set. So you need to implement this kind of logic yourself, either in the callbacks or somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks. I really hoped WPF has a mechanism in place for this, like the existing properties on `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` (AffectsArrange, AffectsMeasure, etc.)

Comment: A mechanism in place for knowing if another property will eventually be set by someone...? I don't think so.

Comment: a mechanism which tells the binding framework to lazy call the onPropertyChanged when instance is created only after all properties are set (SetValue called). This way calling GetValue on a property returns the value

Comment: in other words, a mechanism to tell framework: on control initialization, call the PropertyChangedCallback callbacks after you first set value or ALL dependency properties. This way when PropertyChangedCallback callbacks run, they can evaluate all properties values, like I need

Comment: There is no such mechanism. Besides, implementing your own custom logic in your own custom callbacks should be an easy thing to do.